# c# class graph to Neo4j

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm looking to transform my in memory Plain old C# classes into a neo4j database. 
(Class types are node types and derive from, nodes have a List for "linkedTo")

Rather than write a long series of cypher queries to create nodes and properties then link them with relationships I am wondering if there is anything more clever I can do.

For example can I serialize them to json and then import that directly into neo4j? 
I understand that the .unwind function in the C# neo4j driver may be of help here but do not see good examples of its use and then relationships need to be matched and created separately

Is there an optimal method for doing this? i expect to have around 50k nodes

Comment: You're going to end up massaging your classes in someway to get into the DB - are you tied to the `Neo4j.Driver` or can you use `Neo4jClient`?

Comment: happy to use either route, just looking for a clean one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, first off, I'm using Neo4jClient for this and I've added an `INDEX` to the DB using:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :MyClass(Id)
```

This is important for the way this works, as it makes inserting the data a lot quicker.

I have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string AValue {get;set;}
    public ICollection<int> LinkToIds {get;set;} = new List<int>();
}
```

Which has an `Id` which I'll be keying off, and a `string` property - just because. The `LinkToIds` property is a collection of Ids that this instance is linked to.

To generate my `MyClass` instances I'm using this method to randomly generate them:

```
private static ICollection<MyClass> GenerateMyClass(int number = 50000){
    var output = new List<MyClass>();

    Random r = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        var mc = new MyClass { Id = i, AValue = $"Value_{i}" };
        var numberOfLinks = r.Next(1, 10);  
        for(int j = 0; j < numberOfLinks; j++){
            var link = r.Next(0, number-1);
            if(!mc.LinkToIds.Contains(link) && link != mc.Id)
                mc.LinkToIds.Add(link);
        }
        output.Add(mc);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Then I use another method to split this into smaller 'batches':

```
private static ICollection<ICollection<MyClass>> GetBatches(ICollection<MyClass> toBatch, int sizeOfBatch)
{
    var output = new List<ICollection<MyClass>>();

    if(sizeOfBatch > toBatch.Count) sizeOfBatch = toBatch.Count;

    var numBatches = toBatch.Count / sizeOfBatch;
    for(int i = 0; i < numBatches; i++){
        output.Add(toBatch.Skip(i * sizeOfBatch).Take(sizeOfBatch).ToList());
    }

    return output;
}
```

Then to actually add into the DB:

```
void Main()
{
    var gc = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "neo4j", "neo");
    gc.Connect();

    var batches = GetBatches(GenerateMyClass(), 5000);

    var now = DateTime.Now;
    foreach (var batch in batches)
    {
        DateTime bstart = DateTime.Now;
        var query = gc.Cypher
            .Unwind(batch, "node")
            .Merge($"(n:{nameof(MyClass)} {{Id: node.Id}})")
            .Set("n = node")
            .With("n, node")
            .Unwind("node.LinkToIds", "linkTo")
            .Merge($"(n1:{nameof(MyClass)} {{Id: linkTo}})")
            .With("n, n1")
            .Merge("(n)-[:LINKED_TO]->(n1)");

        query.ExecuteWithoutResults();
        Console.WriteLine($"Batch took: {(DateTime.Now - bstart).TotalMilliseconds} ms");
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Total took: {(DateTime.Now - now).TotalMilliseconds} ms");
}
```

On my aging (5-6 years old now) machine it takes about 20s to put 50,000 nodes in and around about 500,000 relationships.

Let's break into that important call to Neo4j above. The key things are as you rightly suggesting `UNWIND` - here I `UNWIND` a batch and give each 'row' in that collection the identifier of `node`. I can then access the properties (`node.Id`) and use that to `MERGE` a node. In the first unwind - I always `SET` the newly created node (`n`) to be the `node` so all the properties (in this case just `AValue`) are set.

So up to the first `With` we have a new Node created with a `MyClass` label, and all it's properties set. Now. This does include having an array of `LinkToIds` which if you were a tidy person - you might want to remove. I'll leave that to yourself.

In the second `UNWIND` we take advantage of the fact that the `LinkToIds` property is an Array, and use that to create a 'placeholder' node that will be filled later, then we create a relationship between the `n` and the `n1` placeholder. NB - if we've already created a node with the same id as `n1` we'll use that node, and when we get to the same Id during the first `UNWIND` we'll set all the properties of the placeholder.

It's not the easiest to explain, but in the best things to look at are `MERGE` and `UNWIND` in the Neo4j Documentation.

Comment: Also - I've not 'Async'd it, or used bolt.. :/

Comment: Wow thank you Chris that looks great, i am excited to try it out and is much faster than i'd have expected.

Comment: I see how i could modify this to make edges of different types (by changing the :LINKED_TO), i understand it is possible to have properties of edges in neo4j, can these be set as part of the same query?

Comment: The 'AValue' property is picked up in the `.Set("n = node")` line - as this just copies the values of the `node` into `n`. 

To the other question - yes you can, in the same way as with the `.Set("n = node")` - just that instead of `n` you use `r` or whatever identifier you choose to define your relationship with, in the example above I've not given an identifier, but it's just something before the `:`, so like: `.Merge("(n)-[r:LINKED_TO]->(n1)").Set("r.IsCurrent = true")`